# В devtools во вкладке styles не отображаются источники кода, хотя в настройках включена enable css source maps

Tags: css3, google-chrome-devtools

Проверила настройки devtools, переустановила Chrome, в Edge такая же проблема

Comment: Попробуйте обновить страницу с открытым devtools

Comment: Спасибо. Ничего не изменилось